# how to call method on textfieldDidEndEditing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

in my home page there are four textfield. but i want to call method when user write email in eamil textfield.

Note : i just want to call method only when user type email textfield. i dont want to call method on other textfield.

Here is what i tried ::

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    emailVarification()
}
```

but by this code its calling method on every textfield.

Comment: this method only calls when textField resign its first responder ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just Put Condition for your textfield

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
   if textField == txtEmail {  // OR with Tag like textfield.tag == 45
      emailVarification()
    }
}
```

Comment: forgot brackets around if statement.

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 5

Remember to set your delegate:

```
myTextField.delegate = self
```

Then call:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == myTextField {
        // do what is needed
    }
}
```

Read the documentation here: [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619591-textfielddidendediting)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set tag to email textfield and implement textfield's delegate method.

```
optional func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
optional func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
```

In any of this method you need to check the textfield's tag value.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code by this code:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) 
{
if textField == txtEmail 
{  
      emailVarification()
}
Else
{
    //other condition
}
```

}

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: this answer doesn't need so much explanation i just modify the code given in the question

Comment: Yup, I agree. Hence the "Generally" :)

Comment: if you find my answer appropriate can you please upvote it